# Dropdown option from template to views

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am making a project in Django and I want to print out information on the basis of the Dropdown option a user selects from the dropdown list. I am not able to get the output however there are no errors.

This is my template:

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<select name="drop1" class="form-control">
<option>Happy</option>
<option>Sad</option>
</select>
</form>
```

and This is my views.py:

```
if request.method == "POST":
mood = request.POST['drop1']
print(mood)
```

I just want the value of the dropdown to be printed out so I can use it later on.

**EDIT: I made it working, the missing part was submit button.**

```
<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: OK, so what happens?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am not getting the output in the console for print(mood)

Comment: Please show the rest of the view and template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working, the only thing that was missing was a submit button.

```
<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Thanks.